# Synology NAS: deleted files but space won't go down

Tags: linux, nas, storage, du

I've been facing this problem with my Synology lately: I use the Download Station to download torrents in the folder `/volume3/video`.

I now have downloaded `43` files and I can list them running the command `du -skh * | sort -hr`:

[image]

I can also see them in the same directory from the GUI:

[image]

I summed the total space occupied by them and it's around `107 Gb`:

[image]

But when I go to check the disks it seems like `175 Gb` are taken on `/volume3`:
[image]

So I go back one folder and run the same `du -skh * | sort -hr` and I see the the guilty one:

[image]

There is a folder called `@download` which occupies `110 Gb`.

But `110 + 107 = 217 Gb` not `175 Gb`.

And if I run `ls -l` I see this:

[image]

And if I run `du -skh * | sort -hr` again I see this:

[image]

Over all what is the `@download` folder? Is that `eMule`?

What is `@` in the Synology bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of system catalogs in Synology generally start with the
“at” symbol (@).

According to the post
[Download station does not delete temp files](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/46968)
this folder contains torrent seeded files and partial downloads,
where you could recuperate interrupted partial downloads.

User afawaz has remarked in this post :

> I dont know if this post still pending, however, files in @download directory are hard link and not a copy !

Final remarks by user talespin :

> Deleting the file from the destination folder if it is still being
> seeded would not delete the actual file and wouldn't free up any disk
> space either.
>
> In order to delete the file completely and regain the disk space , the
> file must be deleted in the destination folder AND must be removed
> from the download station task/ seeding list.
>
> Also, if a file download is complete and you see the file both in the
> destination folder and the @download folder, note that both are links
> to the same file even though they appear to be separate files. The two
> seemingly separate files are NOT taking up twice the space. If you are
> interested, read up on how hard links work like I did. That will
> explain this behavior.

I would suggest reading this entire post.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your help. I'm going through that guide and I will let you know.

Comment: I have opened a ticket with Synology just to understand the totality of the issue and the total list of the files that I have to delete. I've searched extensively on internet about this issue but I never stabled upon that post. How did you find that? What have you actually typed on Google? Just curious. Thanx

Comment: I don't really remember. Looking in the browsing history, it might have been "Synology "@download" folder (remove|delete)".